# TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined in angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript

I have not got any values from an array using the following TS code:

```
this.dataservice.get("common/public/getAllCategories", null).subscribe(data => {
      //  //console.log('categories'+JSON.stringify( data));
   this.categoriesarray = data;
});
var data = this.items;
var categoriesdata = [];
for (var i = 0; i < data['categories'].length; i++) { // <- Error comes on this line
    categoriesdata.push(data['categories'][i].categoryID);
    this.selspecialization = categoriesdata;
}
this.EditRequest = 'block';   
}
```

My HTML code is:

```html
<button type="button" *ngIf="!userRechargeTable" class=" smallbtns btn roundButton btn-theme blue" (click)="edit()"> 
 Edit
</button>
```

Comment: Are you getting response?

Comment: not a getting a response after click on button gives this error = ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at

Comment: What is the structure of `this.items`? Where is that being set?

Comment: this.categoriesarray = data here is the setup of data

Comment: What's in `items` ?

Comment: categoriesarray data

Comment: we need more information about itemes

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to tell whether this is meant to be one block of code due to the mismatching variable / property names. My guess is that you're trying to process the results of the http request outside of the observable - before the data service has returned the data.

What happens if you try the following:

```
this.dataservice.get("common/public/getAllCategories", null).subscribe(data => {
  //  //console.log('categories'+JSON.stringify( data));
  this.categoriesarray = data;
  // this has been moved inside the observable, and also optimised using the map function
  this.selspecialization = data['categories'].map(x => x.categoryID);
  this.EditRequest = 'block';
});
```

I've taken the following steps:

1. Move code to inside the subscribe(). This is where code should run after the observable (http request in this case) returns a value.
2. Compress your loop into a single map function. Your original `for` loop was unecessary and also performing an unecessary assignment to `this.selspecialization` each time.

Comment: now they are showing this after run= ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
    at SafeSubscriber._next

Comment: You need to provide more information about what is actually going on.

1. Can you post the dataservice.get method. 2. Can you show us the **structure** of the object the dataservice is returning.

Comment: Obviously `categories` is not a property (or at least undefined) on data, so you need to work out what the structure of your data is, and how you get to categories.

Comment: i solved that issue beacuse my var data=this.items is not items is items3....im declare that in the data service.get method...